# I want to purge down my custom build tailwindcss file to smaller in size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, css-purge

This is how my package.json file looks like.

```
 "scripts": {
 "start": "yarn run watch-css && craco start",
 "build": "yarn run build-css && craco build",
 "test": "craco test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
 "build-css": "craco src/index.css -o public/tailwind.css",
 "watch-css": "craco src/index.css -o public/tailwind.css"
 },


 **craco.config.js** looks like
   // craco.config.js
   module.exports = {
    style: {
     postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
      ],
     },
    },
   }
```

this is how my tailwind.config.js looks like:

```
  module.exports = {

  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css}', 
  './public/index.html','./public/tailwind.css'],

  }
```

this is how my style.css file looks like.
/* ./your-css-folder/styles.css */

```
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
```

and i have an uncommpressed file in my public folder named tailwind.css of the size, 4,188kb where all the tailwindcss classes are there and i want to purge this file. how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You should try Just in Time (JIT) mode: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Comment: can not i just do it using script or any purge command in config file ?

Comment: You can run any yarn command and it will purge your css.